# JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

```
hibernate cofiuration
```

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
        scott
        tiger
        10

```
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="beans.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="beans.Contractor"/>
    <mapping class="beans.Regular"/>
</session-factory>
```

[Execution log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APqC8.png)

Comment: Please provide some context on your question. What you are trying to achieve, detailed error messages, stack traces, etc.

Comment: am trying to insert record

Comment: Try to use jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe (/ instead : if xe is a service name rather than a SID)

Answer (score 0):

Check your SID in the HIBERNATE Configuration file:

It should be

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
```

instead of the following, which is wrong.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</property>
```

Also, please do check the following:

- If your DB is UP & Running
- If you are using the correct JDBC driver while connecting to your database
- If your Connection pooling is configured well
- If your HIBERNATE connection pool size is set right and see if you are exceeding that value. If so either decrease the pool size or increase the max_connections setting for the DB

Hope this answers your problem.